# Kafka Consumer/Producer: is it safe to produce in the callback of a production? (max.poll.interval.ms error)

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api, confluent-kafka-python

**TL;DR**: Is there a limitation on re-producing to a topic as part of the callback of a previous production? Consumer hangs with

```
Application maximum poll interval (300000ms) exceeded by 72ms (adjust max.poll.interval.ms for long-running message processing): leaving group
```

I get an error on a consumer-producer process.
Using python 3.9, `confluent_kafka` library, `Producer`/`Consumer` classes.

Process uses `Consumer` to pull data from topic.

It processes the events and uses the `Producer` to produce to a separate topic.

If there is a failure on production because the topic does not exist, the callback uses the `AdminClient` to create it (I have a dependency on the type of message to produce to a certain topic, creating a new topic if the type is coming first time).

The creation of the topic, and the production to the topic happens on the callback function.

When the topic is already created, the application works normally.
However when the topic is not created:

```
2023-05-17T13:31:07.976+02:00   Attempted to produce message to non-existent topic: xxx
2023-05-17T13:31:07.976+02:00   Creating new topic xxx and reproducing message
2023-05-17T13:31:08.747+02:00   Topic "xxx" created
2023-05-17T13:31:09.901+02:00   Produced message on topic xxx
2023-05-17T13:35:35.285+02:00   %4|1684323335.285|MAXPOLL|process#consumer-1| [thrd:main]: Application maximum poll interval (300000ms) exceeded by 72ms (adjust max.poll.interval.ms for long-running message processing): leaving group
```

In this situation, the default `max.poll.interval.ms` looks good enough, especially seeing that the topic is created and the message gets produced quick.
It seems like since the production of the message, until the timeout happens, there are 4'20'' where the process goes idle, and so it never comes back?

Consumer commits happen after the production is finished (to do `at-least-once`)

Could it be because of an accumulation/conflict of callbacks?
Any other idea?

Answer (score 0):

The limitation is in the consumer poll timeout. Creating a topic is a a blocking operation, and may timeout itself, causing the consumer not to heartbeat, and leave the consumer group

Similarly, don't block the producer by calling flush, for example.

You can work around these issues by increasing max poll interval, or pausing the consumer while the topic is created.

Comment: Thanks!
I see. I'll increase `max.poll.interval.ms` to cover for topic creation.
About the topic creation blocking: I'll add the `operation_timeout` setting to leave some time for the adminClient to perform the operation to have more clarity.
About producer: yes I call flush, since I want the consumer to commit after the production is done to ensure at-least-once. Is there a way to make it work differently? 
Is the producer also sensitive to that blocking? (I haven't found a similar timeout setting for Producer)

Comment: Increased `max.poll.interval.ms` to 900000 (15min, 3x default), to no avail. Same behaviour. Seems like it does not come back from the topic creation, even if the topic gets created pretty quickly, and it gets produced to.

Comment: For the producer, you could flush every ten records, for example, and/or flush when consumer reached end of a partition, or after some interval of not reading any data... I was saying that you don't need to flush for every record consumed. The AdminClient should be relatively quick, in my experience, less than minutes for sure. I have seen it take longer when there is authentication required, however, at least when using `kakfa-topics.sh`